# scanf function in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

The output of the following code is very weird for me to understand.Can anybody explain me why it's behaving that way?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char ch='a';

    while(ch!='q')
    {
       scanf("%c",&ch);
       printf("\t%d\n",i);
       i++;
    }

}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Try `scanf(" %c", &ch);` See also: [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](//stackoverflow.com/q/5240789)

Answer (score 0):

Write this statement after your `scanf` statement.

```
while( getchar() != '\n' );  /* flush to end of input line */
```

The next time the loop executes, it auto-fetch the character from the [standard input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068346/what-is-the-standard-input-buffer), so you have to clear it after every `scanf`, so that it is not available for the next  `scanf`. Which is done by the line of code I have above.