# Kernighan and Ritchie C exercise 1-18

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I was trying to complete the task requested by this exercise from the K&R book:

> Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.

I still have to figure out how to implement the first task, but I have this idea for the second one:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define IN 1
#define OUT 1
 
int blank1(char s[], int len){
    int i;
    int c=0;
    for (i=0; i<len;i++){
    if(s[i] == ' ' | s[i] == '\t')
        c++;
    }
    if (c==(len-1))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int get_line1(char s[], int lim){
    int c,i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && ((c=getchar())!= EOF) && c!='\n'; i++){
        s[i]=c;
     }

     if (c=='\n'){
         s[i]=c;
         i++;
     }

     s[i] = '\0';
     return i;
}

int main() {
    char line[MAXLINE];     
    int len;
    int j=1;
    int  i;
    
    while(j){
        len=get_line1(line,MAXLINE);
        if ((blank1(line,len)) == 0) {
        printf("%s", line);
        }

        if (getchar() == EOF){
            j=0;
        }
    }
}
```

The function blank1 takes as input a string `s[]` and the string's length `len`.

Then it cycles for all the string and increases the counter `i` every time it hits a blank or tab. If the string is completely made of blank or tab, such as `\t\t\t\n\0`, then the value of `i` will be the same value of the length of the string - 1 (so to speak, the length of the string excluding the character `\n`). If the string is completely blank, then 1 will be returned, otherwise 0. So in this way if `blank(string,string's length)` returns 1, we know it is a wholly blank string and we can avoid printing it, as the exercise requests.

The problem is that with some outputs this program cuts the first letter. For instance with:

```
Once upon a time\n
There was a little monkey\n
That\n
```

What is printed is:

```
Once upon a time
here was a little monke
hat
```

I can't manage to get why this truncation occurs.

EDIT:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000
#define IN 1
#define OUT 1

int blank1(char s[], int len){
    int i;
    int c=0;
    for (i=0; i<len;i++){
        if(s[i] == ' ' | s[i] == '\t')
            c++;
    }
    if (c==(len-1))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int get_line1(char s[], int lim){
    int c,i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && ((c=getchar())!= EOF) && c!='\n'; i++){
        s[i]=c;
    }

    if (c==EOF)
        return -1;  /////

    if (c=='\n'){
        s[i]=c;
        i++;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char verso[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];
    int len;
    int j=1;
    int  i;
    
    while(j){
        len=get_line1(line,MAXLINE);
        if (len==-1){            ///////////
            j=0;
        }       
        else if ((blank1(line,len)) == 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good attempt-its close! Your `getchar() == EOF` in `main` swallows the first character of newlines!

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR. Mayhaps you were looking for `||`, logical OR. It will still work in this case, but the code looks odd.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks, I just typed the wrong symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getchar() == EOF` in `main` is swallowing your first character from each line (after the first). You are better off calling `getchar` in only one place.

One possibility that causes minimal churn to your current implementation is to keep the only `getchar` call inside `get_line1` and return `-1` from `get_line1` if a `EOF` is read there, to then be handled inside `main`, instead of the call to `getchar` inside `main`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the code, now it should work properly. if the character read at getchar inside get_line1 is EOF, then -1 is returned and if -1 is read n the while-loop then j=0 and this allow the program to exit that loop.

Comment: what i do not yet understand is why the getchar() in the main swalled the first character of every line after the first one. Is there a simple explaination behind this?

Comment: Characters you type into the terminal go an a queue (the `stdin` buffer). The `getchar` function pops (reads and deletes) a character off that queue (waiting for there to be something on the queue if it was empty)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068346/what-is-the-standard-input-buffer

Comment: So in your example: If you type `Once upon a time\nTh` into the terminal the `getchar` calls in `get_line1` would read `Once upon a time\n` and remove them from the queue. 
Then the `getchar` in main would read `T`, and remove it from the queue. You don't assign it to a variable so its forgotten after comparison. The next call to getchar would wait for the following char (`h`)

Comment: thanks, it was very clear

Comment: I'm glad! Would you be able to accept this answer please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Do not program in `main` use functions for similar tasks.

```
char *skipLeadingBlanks(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;

    while((*wrk && *wrk != '\n') && (*wrk == ' ' || *wrk == '\t')) *wrk++;
    memmove(str, wrk, strlen(wrk) + 1);
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[1024];

    while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin))
    {
        skipLeadingBlanks(str);
        if(!*str || *str == '\n') continue;  //empty line
        printf("%s",str);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hxW5zP5Mx